# Text not displayed properly in Firefox

Tags: firefox, 18.04, fonts, text

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

The above pictures are screenshots of the Chemistry Stack Exchange site. The top portion of the words is being covered by something. The same is happening on some non-SE sites too.

[image: Screenshot3]

Why is this happening and how do I correct it? I am using Firefox 60.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Edit:

I use an extension called [Zoom Page WE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/zoom-page-we/?src=userprofile) but disabling it does not solve the problem. Also, changing the font size from preferences does not help either.

Comment: Are you using any style sheet or have you set a larger font size in your browser? And you mention using a "mac" theme in another question? What happens if you use the default theme?

Comment: @DKBose I am using the Community Theme. Default font in Firefox is set to Ubuntu with size 16. But I have installed an extension to Zoom pages as default view is small for me.

Comment: Some elements of some sites don't take kindly to larger font sizes. And, if you can ignore or handle the occasional glitches, I'd say stay with your set-up if that's what you like.

Comment: What happens if you set the default text size, and then zoom with **`ctrl`** and **`+`** once or a few times? Will the top of the letters still disappear?

Comment: @sudodus Doing `ctrl` and `+` two times solves the issue but the page is zoomed too much.

Comment: Well, until you have something better, you can use this method and maybe zoom out one step with **`ctrl`** and **`-`** after reading the first line.

Answer (score 0):

This method works for Firefox 61 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Install the following fonts and everything works fine.

1. ttf-dejavu
2. ttf-liberation

Source: [How do I fix incorrectly displaying fonts? - Firefox Support Forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1140400)